# Problem Heron of Alexandria.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Meaning of the problem is to find two right triangles equal perimeter, but with a predetermined magnification area.

That is necessary to solve a simple system of equations.

$\left\{\begin{aligned}&x+y=z+d\\&xy=qzd\end{aligned}\right.$

$q$ - any given some sort of advance coefficient.

Formula received, but it is interesting to know how others look. Maybe there is another idea and another view of the same.

Comment: I think the first equation should be something of the sort $x+y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z+d+\sqrt{z^2+d^2}$.

Comment: And where there will be a factor?

Comment: And the factor will remain in the second equation, like you already said, $xy=qzd$.

Comment: It is not valid. All too difficult and the most important thing that is not clear. And how can you prove that for any decision factor is?

Comment: What is not valid? What is the most important thing in your second sentence?

Comment: This is really hard to understand. What do your variables represent? How do they relate to areas of triangles?

Answer (score 1):

In Dickson's History of the Theory of Numbers, there are two problems relating perimeter and area of rectangles (*not* right triangles), the second of which is to find two rectangles of equal perimeter, with the area of the second being 4 times the area of the first. Heron finds a solution for this.

Later Maximus Planude (1260-1310) gave a generalization of Heron's problem above, to find two rectangles of equal perimeter such that their areas have a given ratio b:1.
It seems the Planude problem fits with the one you are looking at. Using different letters from yours, with one rectangle of sides $x,y$ and the other with sides $u,v,$ the equal perimeters and area ratio $b:1$ give the equations $$x+y=u+v, \\ x\cdot y = b \cdot u \cdot v.$$
The solution found by M. Cantor was $u=a,\ v=b(b+1)a,$ along with $x=(b+1)a,\ y=b^2a.$
It's easy enough to check that for any value of $b$ this gives a pair of rectangles with the desired properties. Apparently Cantor "noted" that the above gives all the solutions, but in Dicksons footnotes there are some remarks that this may not be all of the solutions. [I myself haven't tried much to see if this solution is complete.]

Comment: When you write the formula mixed $x,y$ and $u,v$ . But it does not matter. The formula does not describe all the decisions. Interest calculation method itself which would allow to find a formula. Yes there a formula other than these?

Comment: @individ Thanks for the notice about mixed variables, now it has been fixed. I also think there are other solutions, and that's what I meant by the reference in Dickson's book about more solutions, which is mentioned in footnotes. However the papers referred to are very old, and I don't have access to them. And I don't know the method which Cantor followed to get his solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think it is necessary to show the formula, in order to more constructive discussion went.
The system:

$\left\{\begin{aligned}&x+y=z+d\\&xy=qzd\end{aligned}\right.$

Solutions can be written as:

$x=qs^2-qps$

$y=qps-p^2$

$z=ps-p^2$

$d=qs^2-ps$

Or this:

$x=qp^2+qps$

$y=qps+(q-1)s^2$

$z=qp^2+(2q-1)ps+(q-1)s^2$

$d=ps$

That's the question. Can I submit solutions in a different way? And what is the idea should be the derivation of?

Comment: If it is to mean right triangles, one with two sides $x,y$ bordering the right angle, and another with two sides $z,d$ bordering the right angle of that triangle, then the perimeters are not proportional to $x+y$ and $z+d$, which makes the "equal perimeter" equation $x+y=z+d$ incorrect, while the ratio of areas is indeed $xy:zd$, so that if the ratio of areas is $q$ the second equation $xy=qzd$ would be correct. In the case of the perimeters you didn't include the two hypotenuses.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean? Condition tasks like simple. Of course you can come up with another condition, but still try to solve in such conditions.

Comment: Am I right that the question should be about rectangles, not triangles?

Comment: The initial conditions of the problem it was about right triangles.  He was looking for triangles with a given area ratio at constant perimeter.

Comment: If it is triangles, then the perimeter includes not only the two "legs" $x,y$ from which area is computed (twice area is then $xy$), but the perimeter also includes the hypotenuse, which by Pythagoras theorem is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ Therefore your setup for the problem for triangles is not correct, since you only use $x+y$ for the perimeter equation.

Comment: It was necessary to write the sum of the legs. In the original problem as it sounds. But I was not too worried about it.  Method for solving a problem in the system equations. Is the equation - you need a method and formula. I got something interesting is there any other option.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14317/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-individ)

Answer (score 0):

In the system of equations:

$\left\{\begin{aligned}&x+y=a+b\\&xy=qab\end{aligned}\right.$

Another solution can be written.

$a=p^2+2qps+(q^2-1)s^2$

$b=2s(p-(q-1)s)$

$x=2qs(p+(q-1)s)$

$y=p^2+2ps-(q^2-1)s^2$

All three formulas derived me just describe all solutions of the system. I think the question can be considered closed.