# Existence of a right triangle

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb N$ with $ab=cd$ and $a+b=c-d$. Prove that there exists a right-angled triangle the measure of whose sides (in some unit) are integers and whose area measure is $ab$ square units.

Substituting $c=a+b+d$ into $ab = cd$ gives $ab = d(a+b+d)$, or equivalently, $d^2+(a+b)d-ab = 0$. The discriminant of this quadratic must be an integer and so
$$\begin{align}
(a+b)^2+4(ab)&=k^2\\
a^2+6ab+b^2&=k^2\\
(a+3b)^2-8b^2&=k^2\\
(a+3b)^2-k^2&=8b^2\\
(a+3b+k)(a+3b-k)&=8b^2
\end{align}$$
Both $(a+3b+k)$ and $(a+3b-k)$ are of the same parity and so they are both even. Thus
$$\left(\frac{a+3b+k}2\right)\left(\frac{a+3b-k}2\right)=2b^2$$ 
How do I continue from here?

Comment: You were on the right track. Spoiler: [Right-angled triangle measure of whose sides are integers](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h226733p1257799).

Comment: Since some sleaze weasel cast a downvote without further explanation, I changed my answer into a comment: While I do not have an answer to your (formal) proof, I can provide you with a numerical example thus showing the existence of such right triangle.
If you take the right triangle with sides 10,24,26 (verify that this is a right triangle), then the area is $0.5(10)(24)=120$. Now we have $ab=cd=120$. Choose $a=6, b=20$ and $c=30, d=4$, we have $a+b=c-d=26$. The purpose is to show that a numerical example is sufficient to prove existence.

Comment: @imranfat (I was just writing the following when I saw your comment here.) There was an answer when I posted (deleted since, after someone downvoted it for reasons unknown) which gave the solution $10^2 + 24^2 = 26^2$ for $a=6, b=20, c=30, d=4$. That is in fact the smallest $n=1, m=5$ solution in the set found at the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @dxiv I found my answer by pure trial and error. But nonetheless it shows existence. It's not worth much for upvotes either but I usually put a downvote if an answer is flat out incorrect and....I reveal my username. But anonymous downvotes happen all the time. Some very reputable people on this site have complained about repeated downvotes without knowing where they're coming from. I don't think it's polite, but that's my take on it...:)

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of questions. If it is necessary to solve the system there can be seen.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779352/problem-heron-of-alexandria/783168#783168  If you are looking for a specific solution form, write down Pythagorean triples and formalized system. In general, what is the connection with  $c$ ; $d$ ?

Comment: A smaller numerical example is $3+2=6-1$, $3\times2=6\times1$, and the 3-4-5 right triangle has area 6.