# $(a,b), (c,d)\in \Bbb{Z}^2$ such that $a+b=c+d$ and $ab=cd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it possible to find $(a,b),(c,d)\in \Bbb{Z}^2$ where $(a,b)\neq (c,d)$ and $a>b$ and $c>d$, such that the following $$a+b=c+d$$ $$ab=cd$$
hold? What was your reasoning?

I have no clue on how to attack this problem. Any help or hints are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779352/problem-heron-of-alexandria

Answer (score 5):

Let $s=a+b=c+d$ and $p=ab=cd$. Then by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) both $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ are the roots of the $2^{nd}$ degree polynomial $x^2 - s x + p = 0$. It follows that $\{a,b\} = \{c,d\}$ and, given the ordering conditions, $a=c,b=d$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by assumption we have
$$(a+b)^2=(c+d)^2.$$
Thus $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$. Hence it follows that
$$(a-b)^2=(c-d)^2.$$
By $a>b$ and $c>d$, we conclude that $a-b=c-d$. Combine with $a+b=c+d$ we have
$$a=c,b=d.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use those two relations to get $a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$. It implies $a^2 - c^2 = d^2 - b^2$. Also you already have $a-c=d-b$. Now as none of $a-c$, $a^2-c^2$, $d-b$, $d^2 - b^2$ are zero, you can divide the first equation by the second to get $$a+c = d+b$$
Now using second equation and this one: $a=d$ and $b=c$. But as $a \gt b$ and $c \gt d$, we get a contradiction. So it is not possible to have such numbers.