# From the equations prove $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> If $a+b=c+d$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ (where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers)
> prove $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$

From $a+b=c+d$ we have:

$$(a+b)^2=(c+d)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab=c^2+d^2+2cd$$

Since $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ then $ab=cd$. So I choose these two equations:

$${ \begin{cases}{ab=cd} \\ {a+b=c+d}\end{cases} }$$
Although solving the system looks easy, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Hint: use the information given to show the quadratic equations $(x - a)(x - b)$ and $(x - c)(x - d)$ are the same, and therefore have the same roots.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003125/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now we have

$$(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab = c^2 + d^2 - 2cd = (c-d)^2$$

so $|a-b| = |c-d|$.

Hence:

$$\max\{a,b\} + \min \{a,b\} = a + b = c+ d = \max\{c,d\} + \min \{c,d\}$$

$$\max\{a,b\} - \min \{a,b\} = |a-b| = |c-d| = \max\{c,d\} - \min \{c,d\}$$

Adding up:

$$2\max\{a,b\} = 2\max\{c,d\}$$

Subtracting:

$$2 \min\{a,b\} = 2\min\{c,d\}$$

so $\{a,b\} = \{c,d\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the polynomials$$P(x)=(x-a)(x-b)\quad\text{and}\quad Q(x)=(x-c)(x-d).$$Note that\begin{align}P(x)&=x^2-(a+b)x+ab\\&=x^2-(c+d)x+cd\text{ (since $a+b=c+d$ and $ab=cd$)}\\&=Q(x).\end{align}Since they are equal, the have the same sets of roots. But the roots of $P(x)$ are $a$ and $b$ and the roots of $Q(x)$ are $c$ and $d$.

Answer (score 1):

One you got the system;
\begin{cases}{ab=cd} \\ {a+b=c+d},\end{cases}
then rest is easy.

Let the common sum be;
$$a+b=c+d=s,$$
and the common product be;
$$ab=cd=p.$$

We know that if we consider the polynomials;
$$(x-a)(x-b) \text{ and } (x-c)(x-d),$$
then both of them are equal to;
$$x^2-sx+p.$$

Thus, we know that $(x-a)(x-b)=(x-c)(x-d),$ implying that $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\};$